# How to popup(open) a bootstrap modal on ajax success

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, jsp, bootstrap-modal

I have a JSP page,say xyz.jsp. I have a button called "send Mail" that has it's onclick() property set to a script function called sendMail(). Sending mail includes sending html data to the controller for generating PDF for which I am using Ajax. Now after the mail is sent successfully ,i want to show a pop-up indicating success. So on Ajax success i want to trigger the popup.

I am using bootstrap modal for popup.

This is my code for button and modal:

```
    <div id="reportbuttons">
                <button type="button" class="btn bg-red waves-effect" onclick="convertToPdf()"  style="margin-right: 5px;float: right; margin-top: -8px">Download</button>  
                 <button type="button"  class="btn bg-red waves-effect"  onclick="sendMail()"  style="margin-right: 5px;float: right; margin-top: -8px">Send Mail</button> 
     <!-- Modal -->
      <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">

          <!-- Modal content-->
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data- 
   dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
              <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data 
    dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

And, this is my script:

```
<script>
function sendMail() {
        let doc = new jsPDF('p','pt','a4');
        doc.setProperties({
            title: 'PDF Document',
            subject: 'subject',
            author: 'ABC',
            keywords: 'generated, javascript, web 2.0, ajax',
            creator: 'XYZ'
        });
        //document.getElementById('reportbuttons').remove();
        document.getElementById('reportbuttons').style.display ="none";
        doc.addHTML(document.body, function() {
    var data = doc.output('datauristring');
                  var reqJson = {};
                     reqJson.machineId = "<%=machineId%>";
                     reqJson.monthYear = "<%=monthYear%>";

                     reqJson.data = data;
                     $.ajax(
                     {
                         url : "sendMail/",
                         type: "POST",
                         dataType: 'json',
                         data : JSON.stringify(reqJson),
                         contentType: "application/json",
                         success:function(data)
                         {
                              $("#myModal").modal();  
                             alert('mail sent successfully');

                             document.getElementById('reportbuttons').style.display ="block";



                         }, 
                         error: function(data)
                         {
                             document.getElementById('reportbuttons').style.display ="block";

                         }
                       });
        });


    }
    </script>
```

I want to show the bootstrap modal popup after the mail is succesfully sent or in other words on Ajax success.

Comment: You can try change code to `$("#myModal").modal('show'); `

Comment: No,it doesn't work. I have already tried it.

Comment: Is the alert working now? Which is below the modal open script.

Comment: @dharmesh you mean the alert('mail sent successfully')? No it's not working.

Comment: Has the ajax call to /sendMail working? are you making the ajax call correctly? 

Use Chrome debugging tools to verify whether network call has been made succesfully?

Comment: @dharmesh Yes, the call to \sendMail is working correctly. I am able to send mails successfully.

Comment: I just removed the attribute [ dataType: 'json' ], This worked for me.Thank you